# In TSQL for MSSMS 2000, how does one change a nonnullable column to be nullable?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I know the column for doing the reverse process (nullable to nonnullable) is

```
ALTER TABLE [Course_Enrollment] ALTER COLUMN [enrollment_date] DATETIME NOT NULL
```

But what about going from nonnullable to nullable? (I don't want to mess things up, by removing the NOT from the above SQL and therefore I might risk changing the default value to NULL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct as you assumed:

```
ALTER TABLE [Course_Enrollment] ALTER COLUMN [enrollment_date] DATETIME NULL;
```

In a nullable column the default is in fact `NULL` unless you specify otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

that's how it is as far as I know, alter column x datetime null.
To change the default value of a column you use the DEFAULT keyword